# Comparing Letter Grades of Two Groups?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference

I apologize: I am new to Cross Validated, so this question may seem very elementary to most.

I would like to compare grades with two groups of students (one group has about 40, the other about 170). However, **I only have access to letter grades on a scale of F, D, D+, C-,....,A**. I am wondering what would be the best way to compare these two groups.

I have thought about converting each of the letters to a 4.0 scale. In other words, set A= 4, A- = 3.7, B+ = 3.3, B = 3,.....C-= 1.3, D = 1.0, F = 0. I initially thought about doing a t-test with these conversions. However, should I be concerned that the difference between D and F is greater than any other two letter grades?

More generally, what would be the best hypothesis test to use in this situation?

Comment: We cannot tell what hypothesis to test: that's a matter for you to decide based on what aspects of these grades you want to compare.  Could you explain what kinds of differences you might be interested in observing between these groups?

Comment: @whuber The null hypothesis would be that the groups have the same mean grade

Comment: On the face of it that makes no sense because--as you know--you can't average letter grades.

Comment: @whuber Yes, that is why I am asking it here!

Comment: The difficulty is that your question is not a definite one.  You somehow need to assign numeric values to letter grades and *then* test whether the means are equal.  Apart from the arbitrary 4.0, 3.7, *etc* convention, you haven't specified any information one could use for assigning numeric values.  It sounds like what you really need to do is *explore the distributions* of letter grades rather than try to conduct a (potentially meaningless) hypothesis test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach that you mention can be a great place to start.  Another good place to start is with a simple barplot (or dotplot) of the data that may show major differences or that even if there is a statistically significant difference, there is no practical difference.  Sometimes in these comparisons the differences in shape end up being more interesting than the difference in mean/median.

You are correct to be concerned if the differences are not all equal.

A couple of other approaches to try (both will probably need some self study on your part if you are not already familiar with them).

First, proportional odds logistic regression.  This is used for ordered categorical data where there is a definite order (A > B > ... > F), but the differences between groups is not necessarily the same.  Grade, as an ordered category, would be the response and group would be the predictor variable.

Second, Interval Censoring methods (this usually is covered as part of survival analysis, failure time analysis, or reliability).  This would assume that each grade represents a range of scores (or percentage of max score), e.g. A means the student earned more than 94%, A- 90%-94%, B+ 87%-90%, ..., F < 50%.  These methods then use maximum likelihood (or partial likelihood) to estimate/compare that underlying distribution on the scores.

Both techniques have similarities under the hood and in some cases are used as approximations for each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "even if there is a statistically significant difference, there is no practical difference"?

Comment: @Guest1234, I probably should have phrased that as "practically important difference".  If you find the mean difference is 0.0001 or smaller, that is probably not big enough to get excited about even if statistically significant.